# Display whole rows in great_expectations dashboard

Tags: python-3.x, data-quality, great-expectations

When an expectation fails, I cannot view on the dashboard (the data docs) the entire row (and not just the column value) which caused the failure. For example, if I have a failure because the maximum value of a numerical column is over a threshold, I can see that value, but I cannot see the related ID column.

I am aware that there exists the option "unexpected_index_list" to get the ids of the dataset which causes the fails, but I would like to be able to view the entire row directly on the dashboard. I also tried the option "include_unexpected_rows", but id does not work as expected.

Any help?